# cloned repo with same name as a local folder and it deleted everything inside

Tags: mac, git, github

Hi there I cloned a repo with the name COMP to documents in my mac with and I forgot there was a folder called COMP there also. I didn't read the warning properly and now all the things that were inside the local COMP folder are gone :( How do I recover those files? It was all my school work.

Comment: You didn't have Time Machine turned on?  Not even a backup to your iCloud drive?

Answer (score 0):

You could use iSkySoft to recover your information.  When a file is deleted a bit on the file is simply turned off in order to tell the system that it is no longer part of its library.  The problem is the more you use your Hard Disk, the more likely your file is to be overwritten.  Below is a link for the free download.  The best scenario is that you use another drive to boot with and mount this drive as a secondary to recover the file.  I know this isn't always possible but it is what is recommented. I don't suppose that you have a backup anywhere on your system.  Did you also store any of those files in your repo somewhere?  Just an idea.  Many times I make several copies of my work in order to make sure I don't accidentally delete it.  Any work that is done better than starting from scratch.

http://www.iskysoft.us/data-recovery-mac/recuva-for-mac.html?gclid=Cj0KEQjwjoC6BRDXuvnw4Ym2y8MBEiQACA-jWZ4kHKRjIkIbwReMtnGM-22bvoza4rncI_6aC9Jijb4aAvno8P8HAQ